# Understanding python builtins like reduce

Tags: python, functional-programming

I refactored code from something like this:

```
def get_ana(word):
    return ''.join(sorted(word.lower()))

def combine_anagrams(words):
    sets = {}
    for word in words:
        ana = get_ana(word)
        sets[ana] = sets.get(ana, []) + [word]

    return sets.values()
```

To something like this:

```
def combine_anagrams(words):
    return reduce(add_ana, words, {}).values()

def add_ana(sets, word):
    ana = ''.join(sorted(word.lower()))
    sets[ana] = sets.get(ana, []) + [word]
    return sets
```

I know this is considered more functional.

But what are the real benefits of the change (in python)?

Memory use, GC, whatever it might be.

Comment: I think the first code is better. It's more readable and they are similar computationally. Your "functional" code violates the ideal that a function should not be changing the state of an object with the `sets[ana] = ...` line so it doesn't have the advantage of being "more predictable."

Comment: Reduced readability? ;) FWIW, [Guido is not a fan of `reduce`](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196), especially when its function arg isn't associative, and it's no longer a built-in in Python 3: it's been relegated to `functools`. Guido wanted to remove it completely, but was forced to keep it after protest ensued.

Comment: @Jared, I realized I'm changing the state. Your point is the tension of my question. However, maybe `{}` as a parameter to reduce sits differently in memory and therefore has benefits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for` loop is, effectively, the same abstraction that recursion provides in functional programming languages. The `reduce` function in Python requires you to package up what would otherwise be the body of a `for` loop in a user-defined function, and such functions incur a layer of overhead that hurts performance.

Python does not optimize recursion as well as most functional languages (really, it doesn't optimize for it at all), because functional languages make the choice to make recursion the sole (or at least primary) means of recursion, while Python provides both `for` and `while` loops to efficiently iterate over data structures.

In the end, using `reduce` will rarely be as readable as a simple `for` loop, will never have better performance, and will usually have *worse* performance due to the need to provide a function to be repeatedly called. It simply allows you to program with the *appearance* of a functional style without any of the usual benefits provided by functional languages to support it.